# how to remove settimeout or any alternate of setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a small animation  in which I used setTimeout . using setTimeout my  animation lag/choppy .can we use `requestAnimationFrame`  instead of setTimeout. I just need to remove some classes after two second.

I think `requestAnimationFrame` is better then setTimeout.

```
 setTimeout(() => {
                    removeClass(customSlider.Components.Elements.slides[prevIndex].querySelector('.rh02-img'), 'fadeOutLeftImg');
                    removeClass(customSlider.Components.Elements.slides[prevIndex].querySelector('.rh02-img'), 'fadeOutRightImg');
                    removeClass(customSlider.Components.Elements.slides[prevIndex].querySelector('.rh08w5'), 'fadeOutText');
                }, 2000)
```

can we convert above code using `requestAnimationFrame` ?

Comment: You don't need to use `requestAnimationFrame` for this - this is actually _a fine_ reason to use `setTimeout` if you want to do _one thing_ after a 2-second-delay. Only use `requestAnimationFrame` for high-fps render loops. Your code that removes those classes is not a render loop - or at least it doesn't look like it.

Comment: Why do you have your own `removeClass` function? The DOM has that built-in.

Comment: removeClass is custom function'

Comment: @user944513 Yes, but **why** do you have a custom function instead of using the DOM's built-in `HTMLElement.prototype.classList.remove('')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #### how to remove `setTimeout` or any alternate of `setTimeout`?
>
> I am creating a small animation in which I used `setTimeout`. Using `setTimeout` my animation lag/choppy

That sounds fine: indeed, `setTimeout` should not be used for *animation loops* as that is what `requestAnimationFrame` is for.

> I just need to remove some classes after two second.

However, *this* is something that you *shouldn't* use `requestAnimationFrame` for.

If you want to run some code after a delay of N-seconds then you should continue to use `setTimeout`[1]: **that is what it's for!**.

However you *can* simplify and shorten your code by using the DOM's built-in `classList.remove`, like so:

```
const removeClasses = function() {
    const elements = customSlider.Components.Elements.slides[prevIndex].querySelectorAll('.rh08w5, .rh02-img');
    for (const e of elements) {
        e.classList.remove('fadeOutText');
        e.classList.remove('fadeOutLeftImg');
        e.classList.remove('fadeOutRightImg');
    }
};

setTimeout( removeClasses, 2000 );
```

---

[1] Or a `Promise`-based reimplementation of `delay()` but that's still not part of JavaScript/ECMAScript's standard library, unfortunately. But I digress...

Comment: thanks @Dai .. it would be great if you give also example of `requestAnimationFrame ` in same example for learning purpose

Comment: @user944513 I can't, because that's not what `requestAnimationFrame` is for. **You cannot (feasibly) use `requestAnimationFrame` (as-intended) to run delayed code**. Giving an example of how to do it would be the same thing as intentionally giving people bad advice.